# Summoning Beast King Barbaros with Majesty's Fiend on the field

Tags: yu-gi-oh

My opponent summoned Majesty's Fiend on their turn, I have Beast King Barbaros in hand. May I summon Beast King without tribute with Majesty's Fiend on the field and what is Beast King's attack when I do?

**Beast King Barbaros**
3000 ATK

> You can Normal Summon/Set this card without Tributing, but its
>   original ATK becomes 1900. You can Tribute 3 monsters to Tribute
>   Summon this card. If you do: Destroy all cards your opponent controls.

**Majesty's Fiend**

> ```
> Cannot be Special Summoned. Monster effects cannot be activated.
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beast King's attack will be 1900 if you normal summon without tribute.

The effect that lets you normal summon him and decrease his attack is a continuous effect, not an activated effect, so Majesty's fiend will have no effect on it.

Comment: Ok this makes sense. If it were a trigger then negating his effect would not change him to 3000. That's why Forbidden Chalice will put him at 3400. I know this picking, I'm trying to make this as accurate as possible. The effect that lets you normal summon him is a summoning condition.